# Facebook Event Picture from API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I seem to have uncovered a bug on the Facebook API.

This is related to the picture related to an event.

When retrieving pictures through the graph for profiles and events you should use the following link:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{eventid}/picture
```

For events that have already occurred (i.e in the past) this works as expected, but when you try to retrieve the picture for a forthcoming event, such as:

https://graph.facebook.com/323879667682222/picture

The actual image can not be found and the default grey icon is shwown.

(ps. the link above is related to an event scheduled to occur on 3rd May)

Can you please confirm that this is a bug, and if there is any other way to retrieve event images from the graph.

Thanks,

Wez

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! Can you please let me know where I can get a full list of fields available for events, these additional fields: pic,pic_big,pic_small were not listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: I've added it as an answer below (instead of a comment) with the additional info you want. Please click accept if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the event profile image with an FQL query like this:

```
SELECT pic, pic_square, pic_small, pic_big FROM event WHERE eid=EVENT_ID
```

This call returns urls to the event profile image in 4 sizes:

- pic - maximum width of 100px and a maximum height of 300px.
- pic_square - width and height of 50px.
- pic_small - maximum width of 50px and a maximum height of 150px.
- pic_big - maximum width of 200px and a maximum height of 600px.

You can read more about the event table fields in the Facebook Developer pages: [FQL Event table.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/)

Comment: FQL is now deprecated. From facebook doc: "As of August 8 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried"

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed a bug, came across the same. I'm doing a FQL query now:

```
    $url = 'http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select name, pic_small, pic_big, pic, host, description, start_time, end_time, location, venue from event where eid="'.$post.'"';


        if($sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($url, NULL, TRUE)){
            $urlimg = $sxe->event->pic_big;
}
```

or with the facebook php api: